# Exercise 1.3.45 (Algorithms 4th edition by Robert Sedgewick) PROBLEM

Tags: algorithm, stack

--------------------Problem statement----------------------------

1.3.45 Stack generability. Suppose that we have a sequence of intermixed push and pop operations as with our test stack client, where the integers 0, 1, ..., N-1 in that order (push directives) are intermixed with N minus signs (pop directives). Devise an algorithm that determines whether the intermixed sequence causes the stack to underflow. (You may use only an amount of space independent of N—you cannot store the integers in a data structure.) Devise a linear-time algorithm that determines whether a given permutation can be generated as output by our test client (depending on where the pop directives occur).

Solution: The stack does not overflow unless there exists an integer k such that the first k pop operations occur before the first k push operations. If a given permutation can be generated, it is uniquely generated as follows: if the next integer in the output permutation is in the top of the stack, pop it; otherwise, push it onto the stack.

---

I only have a problem with understanding this part: Devise a linear-time algorithm that determines whether a given permutation can be generated as output by our test client (depending on where the pop directives occur).

I saw there are solutions on google on how to solve this exercise but i couldn't find an explanation of how it is solved. Can anyone explain? Thank you

Comment: _I saw there are solutions on google_ - please post one for which you like to get an explanation. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The first step is quite simple. To determine whether a sequence of steps causes an over- or underflow, we use the following algorithm, where k is the size limit of the stack and the list of instructions is a list of either PUSH or POP:

In Python:

```py
def undeflows(lst):
    count = 0
    for x in lst:
        if x == PUSH:
            count += 1
        else:
            # We know that x == POP
            if count == 0:
                return True
            count -= 1
    return False
```

For the second part, the key is that we can extrapolate what the sequence of operations must have been to produce the given output. Consider the following algorithm:

In Python:

```py
def test_permutation(perm):
    stack = []
    next_to_read = 0
    for val in perm:
        if val >= next_to_read:
            # in this case, we haven't pushed val yet. We'll need to push
            # next_to_read to val inclusive, then pop val.
            stack.extend(range(next_to_read, val))
            next_to_read = val + 1
        # Otherwise, we must have already pushed val. We must check to make sure
        # we can pop it.
        elif stack and stack[-1] == val:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    # at this point, stack should be empty.
    return not stack
```

If we are guaranteed that the input actually is a permutation of 0, 1, ..., n - 1, then we can modify the code to

```py
def test_permutation(perm):
    stack = []
    next_to_read = 0
    for val in perm:
        if val >= next_to_read:
            # in this case, we haven't pushed val yet. We'll need to push
            # next_to_read to val inclusive, then pop val.
            stack.extend(range(next_to_read, val))
            next_to_read = val + 1
        # Otherwise, we must have already pushed val. We must check to make sure
        # we can pop it.
        elif stack[-1] == val:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            return False
    # at this point, stack should be empty.
    return True
```